# Create Table Exception In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm newbie in laravel and trying to create the following table. The code below is inside my "route.php" file ::

```
Route::get("userDatabase", function(){
    Schema::create("users", function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 32);
        $table->string('email', 320);
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
});
```

when i visit `http://localhost/laravel/public/userDatabase` i get the following Exception ::

```
RuntimeException
PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.sessions' doesn't exist
```

The database configuration in the "database.php" file is correct, and there is nothing wrong with that.

What am i doing wrong and what is causing this Exception?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has actually nothing to do with your code, it's an issue because you use the database session driver without creating the correct table for it, so when it tries to initialize the session (and read eventual data that may be in it) it fails.

Either create the missing session table with a schema like this :

```
Schema::create('sessions', function($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

(put that in a database migration and run it)

Or change your session driver to something that doesn't require a database, like the `file` driver.

I suggest you also read the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/session) about sessions.

Comment: Or instead manually creating the table, call `artisan session:table && artisan migrate` to let laravel handle this for you.